# Data not refreshing "DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been working with Firebase for a long time now, so far so good except the following scenario.

Sometimes I notice that my app doesn't get fresh data anymore. I'm listening for changes with an active listener and I do have the `keepSynced` set to `true`.

When that happens I see the following on my logs:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found
```

The problem gets resolved if I logout the user and login again. I know I have all the `SHA-1` Keys in place and the JSON file from Firebase up to date.

Does anyone knows what's causing this? It's like as if the user was being logout or the token that they use internally is no longer valid.

Comment: Enable debug logging: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)`.  The output is very detailed and will likely be helpful.