# Firebase automatic login - expiration / refresh required?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an App where a user can optionally choose to sign-in to Firebase via Google and compete online using the Firebase database.  I don't force users to sign-in, it is completely at their request.  I have sign-in activity to handle this code, and then users never return to this activity unless they want to sign-out.

Once signed in, is it necessary that I refresh the automatic login token, or call the Google auto-sign in code?  I have not been doing this and the App generally functions as expected.

Recently I have seen some issues where the code believes it is "signed in", but fails to communicate with the database (it looks like there is no network connection).  The fix is to return to my sign-in activity - sign-out and then back in again, and everything kicks back into life.

This is the only code I use in the main activity:

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mFirebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

if (mFirebaseUser != null)
{
    // assume we are signed-in, try to access database
}
else
{
    // assume we are signed-out (or have never signed in).
}
```

Is this naive?

*07/02/17 update...*

When it is failing to communicate with Firebase, I get the following warning:

**W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.**

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() returns the expected result

Comment: try to implement an Auth State Listener and you will get informed when maybe the User will be logged out or when the Access Token will be refreshed https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

Comment: @MichaelMeyer thanks for the response.  I'm using the Auth State listener in my sign-in activity - i'm guessing I need to have one also in my main activity, or somehow call the sign-in activity in the back-ground at start-up to listen / respond accordingly.

Comment: Authentication tokens are auto-refreshed: you don't need to write any code for that. If you'd like to know when the user's authentication state changes or when their token is refreshed, you can attach an auth state listener. But even without that listeners, the token will refresh automatically.

Comment: If you're having a problem that seems to mismatch what I wrote above, please post the [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - thanks for the fast response.  It looks like I've hit the same problem that is described here: [How deal with cold start of an app where user has beeing logged with Firebase at previous run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904910/how-deal-with-cold-start-of-an-app-where-user-has-beeing-logged-with-firebase-at), although your comment about the token being auto-refreshed would explain why I don't usually have an issue.  No-one is complaining, so it may be just a problem I'm seeing when running from Android Studio

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - actually I believe this is the same issue as [data not refreshing...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892074/data-not-refreshing-dynamitemodule-local-module-descriptor-class-for-com-googl?rq=1).  Any idea what could be causing this.  I'm now seeing it regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching online and trying different solutions listed on Stack Overflow, I finally discovered that when I'd added a new FLAVOR to my project and downloaded the updated **google-services.json** file, the file that Google had auto-created was missing 2 sections from the OAUTH client section on both my initial project and my new FLAVOR.

Both **client_type 1** sub-sections were missing from the oauth_client section as follows.  The client_type 3 section was still present.

Missing sections:

```
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "[client_id]",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "[package]",
        "certificate_hash": "[hash]"
      }
    },
    {
      "client_id": "[client_id]",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "[package_name]",
        "certificate_hash": "[hash]"
      }
    },
```

So it was effectively a regression from a working solution introduced when adding a FLAVOR.  The project under the flavor was missing the **SHA-256 key**, which I added, and then went back to a page to add firebase to the project.  When I recreated **google-services.json** everything was this time generated (as expected).  I cannot say for definite if it was adding the SHA-256 key, or the  "Add Firebase to Project" weblink which led to client_type 1 sections being correctly created.

To recap - my problem was that the App appeared to work correctly for existing users.  It was failing if you'd logged out, or if you were logging in for the first time, and the problem appeared to be that the Auth-token was not correctly refreshing.

[EDIT 28/02/2017]
After a few good weeks, the problem returned even with the good **google-services.json** file, so I have gone back to the solution provided here: [Firebase for Android - W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided authentication credentials are invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221491/firebase-for-android-w-persistentconnection-pc-0-provided-authentication-cr)

I had discovered that I had the following code:

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mFirebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

I'd made mFirebaseUser static, and so I think the problem was masked by having correct information prior to accessing the database.  In the provided link it explicitly states that database access must occur after initialising/renewing the current user credentials.  My current solution is to add a *AuthStateListener* as described and initialise/access the database afterwards providing mFirebaseDatabase!=null:

```
authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        mFirebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
           mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        }
    }
};
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should implement an Auth State Listener in your corresponding Activites. Then you will get informed e.g. when the User was logged out or the Auth Token were refreshed

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener